# vue router dynamic alias

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I would like to alias an unmatched route to an error 404 page without changing the url.

In the router config there is a catchall alias like so:

```
{
    path: '/404',
    alias: '*',
    name: 'error',
    component: Error
}
```

When a user visit `my-site.com/random-inexisting-url`, the url doesn't change and it displays the error page.

It works fine until here.

---

Now I would like to do the same with dynamic routes. For example, there is a route like `my-site.com/pages/:id` and the user visits `my-site.com/pages/inexisting-id`.

The `id` param is used to fetch an API, so there is no automatic redirection to the error page if the API returns null. It is possible to redirect to the `/error` page with `router.push({ name: 'error' })` or a navigation gard, but it will change the url to `/error`.

**Is it possible to keep the original url, but still display the error page?** 
(something like `router.aliasTo({name: 'error' })`

Comment: I don't think so. but you can load different component like https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/76#issuecomment-278175628